# Why are the returning and non-returning std::functions castable?

Tags: c++

Why does this work?

```
std::function<int(int)> ret_func = [](int x) { return x; };
std::function<std::string(int)> ret_func1 = [](int x) { return std::to_string(x); };
std::function<void(int)> func = ret_func;
std::function<void(int)> func1 = ret_func1;
```

Because of type erasure of the functor in the `std::function`? This cast will not work between any type of function; for example, if you change arguments and try to assign to another `std::function` why wouldn't this work? Because the return value does not change the type of the functor but arguments do?

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/enfYWz)

Comment: `std::function` doesn't require exact signature, but "compatible", `int`/`std::string` can be converted to `void`.

Comment: More accurately, `std::function<void(params)>` can call any function that takes `params` and returns *anything*, the `std:function` will simply ignore what the function returned and will itself return `void` (nothing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think of it as casting, think of it as the `std::function<int(int)>` being assigned to the `std::function<void(int)>` as a value.

1. `std::function<void(int)>` can be assigned any function-like object `fun` that can be invoked like `static_cast<void>(fun(v))` (`v` being an `int`).
2. `std::function<int(int)>` easily fits that criteria since you can do:

```
void foo(std::function<int(int)> fun) {
  fun(12);
}
```

So `std::function<int(int)>` **has** to be assignable to `std::function<void(int)>`. That's all there is to it.

How the library implements this doesn't really matter. It just has to in order to fulfil the API contract.

**Disclaimer:** This is a tiny bit of an oversimplification. The standard actually has a few provisions for `std::function` -> `std::function` assignment, like move-construction and dealing with unassigned `std::functions`s. However, the semantic principles outlined in this answer still hold as an explanation.

As asked, the relevant parts of the standard:

**[func.wrap]**

> template function(F f);
> Constraints: F is Lvalue-Callable ([func.wrap.func]) for argument types ArgTypes... and return type R.

> A callable type F is Lvalue-Callable for argument types ArgTypes and return type R if the expression INVOKE(declval<F&>(), declval()...), considered as an unevaluated operand, is well-formed ([func.require]).

**[func.require]**

> Define INVOKE(f, t
> 1
> , t
> 2
> , …, t
> N
> ) as static_­cast<void>(INVOKE(f, t
> 1
> , t
> 2
> , …, t
> N
> )) if R is cv void, otherwise INVOKE(f, t
> 1
> , t
> 2
> , …, t
> N
> ) implicitly converted to R.

So since `std::function<int(int)>` is Lvalue-Callable for `void(int)`, then it is a valid value. Now, in practice, this doesn't *actually* come into play because of other constructors/assignment operators will intercept it, but the semantics remain.

Comment: any chance you have this `std::function` assignment part of standard?

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg ammended the answer with what I think are the relevant sections.